# Getting HTML values from a page source using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to take html source lines from page source using javascript.
In my case the source is

```html
<div id="green" class="orange">
  Hello
</div>
<div id="red" class="blue">
  Hello
</div>
```

In the above source, I have to take the id value as output, i.e "green" and "red" and not the text "hello" using Javascript, please help me with it.

Comment: Using Java or Javascript. Make sure Java != JavaScript

Comment: I am using Java here for taking the values

Comment: Where is your java code?

Comment: Actually am new to crawling, i can take the text hello, but i need the id values.

Comment: are you using Servlet or struts ? . better provide java Code . i think you want Id value as a output

Comment: Element id= document.getElementById("green");, by this i can take hello. But how to take value green itself.

Comment: try this : --> Element id= document.getElementById("green").innerHTML;

Comment: That inner html is not working, still unable to take that id value.

Comment: I didn't understand it. What is the point to find the id value with the id value is used to find the element?

Comment: If you want to crawl the html content I suggest you to do this server-side and use some kind of [dom parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) so you gonna have the entire html page as a big tree so you can navigate from all elements and access any attribute or element.

Comment: In my case the id value is dynamically generated every time the page source is loaded, so i cannot give the static id. So i am trying to take the dynamic id of the page somehow. In the example i have given first time it will be "green", second time it will be "red", that is the issue here. Can you understand my issue?

Comment: You can access via another attribute. Can you use jquery to solve this?

Comment: But we here are using jsoup to do crawling here.

Comment: @Avles below solutions hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can access via class.

```
document.querySelector('div.orange').id
```

Comment: What? Of course it's a anwser. And it use native browser selector, instead of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery:

> $('div').attr('id')

Answer (score 0):

**After Edit** it is working example

To get orang class ID try this

```
$(".orange").attr('id');
```

And for Blue class try this one

```
$(".blue").attr('id');
```

Example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54nLM/597/)